# For positive integers $x$, $y$, and positive real $k$, if $\frac{x+1}{y+k}=\frac{y}{x}$, then $k\geq1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I saw this problem in the prep book for the USAMO in the Algebra section, but I don’t know how to tackle it. As the problems before were all solvable by factoring/Cauchy-Schwarz, I have tried finding a way to factor/rearrange this into a C.S.-form , but I have made no progress at all. As I’m getting quite frustrated with this problem I would appreciate all help!

> Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers and $k$ be a positive real number for which $$\frac{x + 1}{y + k} = \frac{y}{x}$$
> is satisfied.
>
> Prove that $k\geq1$ holds.

**My thoughts:** After rearranging we arrive at $(x+1)x$ which must at least be 2. And $y(y+k)$ where $y$ is at least $1$. So we have
$$x^2+x=y^2+yk$$
and $$\frac{x^2+x-y^2}{y}=k$$
This obviously holds for $x>y$, but for $y<x$ I am running into difficulties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&
\frac{a^2+a-b^2}{b}=c
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{a^2+a-b^2}{b} > 0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a^2+a-b^2 > 0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a^2+a > b^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(a+1)^2 > b^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a+1 > b
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a\ge b\;\;\;\text{$\bigl($for integers $x,y$,$\;$if $x+1 >y\;$then $x\ge y\bigr)$}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
c=\frac{a^2+a-b^2}{b}\ge \frac{b^2+b-b^2}{b}=1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: This is a really cool answer, the bound must be really weak then right?

Comment: Let's [have a discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121267/discussion-between-quasi-and-lone-student).

Comment: I've removed several comments from this answer. I removed them because they were going in circles. From my perspective, every forward implication here is very clear with the possible exception of $a^2 + a > b^2 \implies (a+1)^2 > b^2$, but this is true because $(a+1)^2 = a^2 + a + (a + 1) > a^2 + a > b^2$. Or perhaps the implication that $(a+1)^2 > b^2 \implies a+1 > b$, which is true because $a$ and $b$ are positive. This answer seems nice to me.